# Unique code for unique visitor on button click in html

Tags: javascript, html

I need a similar approach as this one

```
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />
    <p id="message" >Get Referral Code/p>

    function GetValue()
    {
    var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
    }
```

but what I need is to give a unique code from my list of 1000 unique codes to unique visitor.  The problem with this code is every time I refresh the page the code just loop

Comment: Doing this client side won't produce consistent result. You should generate it server side if it's really referral code.

Comment: You're probably looking to make use of `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, or possibly even a back-end database to associate the code to each particular user.

Comment: You need to track your unique visitors. Ideally, you need a server side script.